# how to convert a JSON object into a JSON array in Mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Input:

{
"abc": "xyz",
"pqr": "def"
}

Expected Output:

[
{
"abc": "xyz",
"pqr": "def"
}
]

Expecting the output mentioned.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclosing an object -or any construct- in bracket will return an array with that item.

Example:

```
[payload]
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]If you have a sing json object you could do this...

Comment: How is your answer different from the below answer? Please don't use image where it is possible with text

Comment: Consider using text over screenshots the next time.